# how to get sed to replace part of a line that start with a range of numbers

Tags: awk, sed, perl

How can I get sed or perl to make the following changes to a line
from :

```
41 * * * * /vend/oracle/util/bin/rmp_udump.ksh
```

to:

```
##SHUTDOWN_MAINT##41 * * * /vend/oracle/util/bin
```

for all lines that begin [0-9]. In vi this works:

```
%s/^[0-9].*/##SHUTDOWN_MAINT##&/
```

Comment: Did you also need to remove the path name element at the end (rmp_udmp.ksh, in your example)?

Comment: Does your `sed` support the `-i` for "in-place" editing of files?

Comment: Are you sure about your vi command? I don't see how it would remove one of the asterisks and the trailing `/rmp_udump.ksh`.

Comment: I am just looking to add the prefix data so that I can stop the cron from running then another script to remove the additional data

Answer (score 1):

For the equivalent of your `vi` command, in `perl`:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^\d/##SHUTDOWN_MAINT##$&/' your-file
```

Or:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(?=\d)/##SHUTDOWN_MAINT##/' your-file
```

Or:

```
perl -pi -e '$_ = "##SHUTDOWN_MAINT##$_" if /^\d/' your-file
```

Comment: thank you so much for the command what would the perl command be to remove the additional data to bring the file back to original entry

Comment: To revert the changes, the command would be: `perl -pi -e 's/.*?(?=\d)//' your_cron_file'` This is assuming you made the change comment as shown.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Thank you so much for all your help I seem to be having a problem with the version of Perl that i use if I use /usr/opt/perl5/bin/perl5.10.1
 the code works if I use /usr/local/perl5.16.1/bin/perl
 I get the following error Scalar found where operator expected at /home/vw110228/Perl/perl_uncroncom.pl line 6, near "'s/.*?(?=\d)//' $1"

Comment: Hi there to make the issue complete I am trying to pass in a file to this command using the following perl_uncroncom.pl line 6, near "'s/.*?(?=\d)//' $1 where $1 is the file of my choice.

Comment: @VirginiaWalters, it sounds like you're trying to have `perl` interpret a shell script.

Comment: No I ran this command in 5.10 perl and it worked now when running the same command in 5.16 I get the error